# Draw line with d3.js using separate, fixed x & y input arrays

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have separate x and y arrays and want to connect the dots using a line path.  This seems to be about the simplest possible example but I don't quite grok the writing the function.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<script src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"> </script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xdata = d3.range(20);
var ydata = [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15, 15, 11, 10, 5, 5, 4, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 8, 10];

var xscl = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(xdata))
    .range([0, width])

var yscl = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(ydata))
    .range([height, 0])

var slice = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xscl(xdata[d]);})
    .y(function(d) { return yscl(ydata[d]);})

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", slice)

</script>
</body>
```

But it returns an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, so clearly the function returned by `d3.svg.line()` doesn't have the right form. What's wrong?  I pray not a typo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Elijah's spot on remark about `d3.svg.line`, I think it is hard to go about this without putting the array as expected by this function. So:

```
var xy = [];
for(var i=0;i<xdata.length;i++){
   xy.push({x:xdata[i],y:ydata[i]});
}
```

I made other changes regarding `.domain` and the `slice` function per se. Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/88W7k/) with the results of my effort.

Comment: Thank you.  I removed the `i` from the `d3.svg.line` function.  I'm coming from `R` and the `JS` data structures are givimg me hell. They are hard to read and seem to be overly complex.  I guess `d3.js` wants data in this particular format pretty regularly, which is fine, but I haven't found where this is documented. I've either missed it or it's assumed, which is tough on noobies.  Thanks much, I've learned something very useful here.

Comment: YMW. D3 has its fair amount of challenges...and we all love it :)

Comment: I put the final version in [gist](https://gist.github.com/bryanhanson/11344247) with additional comments.  It might help others who are learning the `d3` way of thinking.

Answer (score 7):

I know it has been more than a year, but I had to deal with this problem also.
Storing path data  (x, y) in 2 separate arrays is much more memory efficient than the 2D array `d3.svg.line` expects. For a very large number of points, the accepted answer is also inefficient by looping through all elements to create the 2D array.

The solution I found without adding any loops is write a wrapper function for `d3.svg.line` as follows:

```
var line = function(x, y){
    return d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { return x[i]; }) 
    .y(function(d,i) { return y[i]; })
    (Array(x.length));
}
```

and then set the path attributes:

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(x_array, y_array))
```

See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3cv3T/135/)

Answer (score 2):

d3.svg.line can only take one data source. However, you can feed it your two data sources by putting them into an object:

```
newData = {x: xdata, y: ydata};

 var slice = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d,i) { return xscl(d.xdata[i]);})
  .y(function(d,i) { return yscl(d.ydata[i]);})
```

Then point your line function at newData and you should be set:

```
 svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", slice(newData))
```

Typically, though, you're better off building an array of coordinate pairs, since that's what it's expecting.

Comment: Would you mind looking at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aD8HV/) ?  The path is being created, but has no data points.

Comment: Looks like `slice(xy)` is `null`.